# Calculated range based upon some criteria

Tags: google-sheets

Given this layout:

```
+--------+      +--------+
| A  | B |      | A  | B |
+----+---+      +----+---+
| 1  |   |      | 1  | 6 |
| 2  |   |      | 2  |   |
| 3  |   |  =>  | 3  |   |
|    |   |      |    |   |
| 4  |   |      | 4  | 9 |
| 5  |   |      | 5  |   |
|    |   |      |    |   |
+----+---+      +----+---+
```

I want to have the sum of `A1:A3` in `B1` and the sum of `A5:A6` in `B5`. This is trivial. what i really want is a formula which calculates the range `A1:next_free_cell_below_in_a` and `A5:next_free_cell_below_in_a`.

**Bonus**: Can I use some other "patterns" / "criterias" as well?

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took some time but here it is:

```
 =SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,INDEX(ROW(A1:A),MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:A),0))-ROW(A1),1))
```

how it works:

1. we want the sum of a range. `OFFSET` provides a range, based upon a starting point (optional offset in x and y) and then some dimensions.
2. `A1` is the reference corner, `0` and `0` are the offsets (we want to stay in the `A` column). the `1` at the end means 'only the A column'.
3. the 'height' parameter of the `OFFSET` function is calculated by `row of empy cell` - `ROW(A1)` (which is the starting cell)
4. `INDEX(ROW(A1:A), MATCH(TRUE, ISBLANK(A1:A), 0))` calculates the rownumber of the first empty cell below `A1`.

if someone could explain the reason why 4. works as it does, please comment my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For this solution, one dummy row (1:1) & one dummy column (C:C) is used.

**Formula:**
`B2` contains `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),C2,"")`, then copied down to `B3:B7`
`C2` contains `=A2+IF(ISBLANK(A3), 0, C3)`, then copied down to `C3:C7`

```
   |    A    |    B    |    C
---+---------+---------+---------
 1 |         |         |         
 2 |       1 |       6 |       6  (ie. 3+2+1)
 3 |       2 |         |       5  (ie. 3+2)
 4 |       3 |         |       3  (ie. 3)
 5 |         |         |       9 
 6 |       4 |       9 |       9  (ie. 5+4)
 7 |       5 |         |       5  (ie. 5)
```

`A:A` : Data
`B:B` : **Desire output**
`C:C` : Dummy column

I am not so sure about what you mean by other "patterns" / "criterias". Maybe you can describe more about that.

Comment: Nice formulas !

Answer (score 0):

With the following piece of code, you can do just that.

### Code

```
function mySum(range) {
  var sum = 0, counter = 0, c = 0, output = [], index;
  for(var j = 0, jLen = range.length; j < jLen; j++) {
    if(range[j].indexOf('') !== 0) {
      sum += range[j][0];
      counter++;
    } else {      
      index = c * (j - counter);
      output[index]= sum;
      sum = 0;
      c = 1;
      counter = 0;
    }
  }  
  return output;
}
```

### Explained

First a number of variables are declared and set (`= 0` or `[]`). In the `for` loop, a check is made whether, during the iteration, the value is an empty string (`''`) or not. Key is to reset the counter and the sum, after hitting an empty cell.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

Wasn't able to implement your solution. The script also makes it possible to easily implement other tasks, other than a summation.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Calculated range based upon some criteria](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1hCSehDj2CmSy_YrFX-aiTeFRG8afNNtdGg4Q6etLNc4/edit?usp=sharing)**.
Add the script under *Tools>Script Editor* and press the save button (no authentication needed).